# AttributeError: 'name_Funcition/task' object has no attribute 'GET' - Django, Celery + RabbitMQ

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm starting Celery+RabbitMQ to use async functions on my Django system and I'm facing some issues.

As I understand it, when using Celery+RabbitMQ, the function that I insert in my tasks.py file will be executed "outside" my Django system, and I believe that I am not able to use/separate it all correctly.

I organized my project as follows:

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

**project/**init**.py**

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**projetec/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.conf import settings
import os
from celery import Celery

# Defina o módulo de configurações padrão do Django para o programa 'celery'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery(
    'proj',
    broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
    backend='rpc://',
    include=['app.tasks']
    )

# Startando o app config
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()

# Usar uma string aqui significa que o trabalhador não precisa serializar
# o objeto de configuração para processos filhos
# - namespace='CELERY' significa todas as chaves de configuração relacionadas ao celery
#   deve ter um prefixo `CELERY_`.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**app/tasks.py**

```
@shared_task(
    bind=True, # Chama funções do celery
    max_retry=3, # Maximo de tentativas de execução
    default_retry_delay=20, # Tempo entre as tentativas em segundos
    autoretry_for=(TypeError, Exception), # Auto retry caso algum erro na tupla aconteça
    )
def gerar_pdf(request):

print('Buscando o dashboard pelo uuid')
    dashUUID = request.GET.get('uuid')
    dashObject = Dashboard.objects.get(uuid=dashUUID)
    print('UUID = ', dashUUID)
    
    In this step I'm trying to run a script that downloads a report in PDF format and sends it to my customers' email
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
def DashboardViewPdf(request):

gerar_pdf.delay()

return render(request, template_name, context)
```

To perform this task with Django, I added a button in my frontend that calls the "DashboardViewPdf" function. But when executed, it returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'gerar_pdf' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

and installed RabbitMQ as follows

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server

Create a user, a virtual host and give permissions to that user on the virtualhost:
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user myuser mypassword
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

How can I make django attributes run in my task?

Comment: I created a "hello world" function and everything seems to work with this simple function. I'm having trouble adding my function to download PDFs with selenium which is a bit more complex

Comment: I tried to add the "Dashboard" parameter (which is the model responsible for the UUID) in my function, but, in this scenario, the function doesn't get to be executed by celery, before that I get the error: "Object of type ModelBase is not JSON serializable"

Comment: If I try to perform a serialization directly in the views.py function with "gerar_pdf.delay(JsonResponse(Dashboard, safe=False))" I get the error "In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False ."